# log parsing with sed or grep

Tags: shell, sed, grep, tail

I want to grab data from this kind of log.

> Nov 12 13:46:14 Home cxxd[8892]: 208 11/12 13:46:14|  qc=IN (1), qt=A (1), query="www.yahoo.com."

Implemented this which gives me the URL. But does not work with "TAIL -F" so that I could monitor live just the urls.

> tail -100 /var/log/system.log | grep "query=" | sed -e "s/.*query=//" | sed -e "s/\"//g" | sed -e "s/.$/ /"

Please suggest or enhance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I expect your multiple `sed` scripts *do* work with `tail -F` output, just not as you expect.

The C standard IO libraries will perform buffering to improve performance. The IO library can do (a) no buffering (b) line-buffering (c) block-buffering. The line-buffering is normally chosen if the output is going to a terminal. But if the output is going to a file or pipe, then block buffering is normally chosen. (It's more complicated than this -- the behavior changes if the file descriptor in question is being used for stdout or stderr or another file. See `setvbuf(3)` for full details.)

So, while the block-buffering you're seeing now is probably better for *performance*, it does mean you can wait a while before ever seeing any output, as each command will eventually accumulate a *block* of data. At least `grep(1)` allows the `--line-buffered` command line option to use line-buffering -- and `sed(1)` allows the `--unbuffered` command line option to flush output buffers more often. So try this:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep --line-buffered "query=" | sed -u -e "s/.*query=//" | sed -u -e "s/\"//g" | sed -u -e "s/.$/ /"
```

(I didn't find any similar options for `tail(1)`, but even if it sends blocks of data to the others, the changes to `grep(1)` and `sed(1)` will drastically help.)

Comment: awesome. just the option for sed is -l instead of -u for me. works great! thanks!

Comment: What's your platform? I'm surprised about the different option. (My `sed` is `GNU sed version 4.2.1`.)

Comment: im on mac. I tried sed -v and sed --version, but does not give me version. wierd! :)

Comment: Heh, then _probably_ a BSD-derived `sed`, though maybe they got a Unix-licensed version instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try reducing the number of pipes by replacing multiple calls to `grep` and `sed` to one with `awk`:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log | awk -F'=' '/query=/ { sub(/^"/, "", $NF); sub(/."$/, "", $NF); print $NF }'
```

...which takes every line matching "query=" and grabs everything after the last '=', replaces the first '"' and the trailing '."' and prints the result.

Comment: wow, much cleaner. this works as well. But I already picked up the answer which works as well.

Comment: If only StackOverflow had some mechanism for indicating that an answer is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Try the tail -f and grep argument --line-buffered

Comment: > tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep "query=" works fine but having problems extracting just url with sed. also tried tail -f /var/log/system.log | grep --line-buffered "query=". same result

Comment: example line from you does yeld the `www.yahoo.com` with current sed expressions for me. would you add expected output if `www.yahoo.com` is not?